# Optical Isolation of BNC trigger?

Tags: isolation, hardware, bnc, optical

I am wondering if there is a more practical way to provide optical isolation for a BNC trigger. I am currently using the following: https://www.eagleharbortech.com/product-categories/fiber-optic-isolation/

These are several hundred dollars each and I am thinking a cheaper option or other work-around should be available.

Comment: Describe the input signal, what the output needs to drive, how accurate the timing needs to be, how much voltage isolation you need, and whether that isolation needs to be safety-rated or merely functional.

Comment: Some ferrite transformer would be have much faster response than optocoupler.

Comment: There probably is, but without knowing your requirements I'd be speculating.